# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oscar.app' in Django Oscar

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-oscar, django-model-field

I just installed `Oscar` module for my website and all tables are stored in database, but now i am using this module on my urls.py file but it's giving me an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oscar.app'`
Please help me to solve this issue...
Here is my urls.py file....

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.contrib import admin
from oscar.app import application

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
(r'', include(application.urls)),
# path('', include("frobshop.urls")),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to follow setup instructions for Oscar 1.6 with an installed Oscar version of 2.0, which no longer has `oscar.app`.

See https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/internals/getting_started.html, where this has changed to:

```
url(r'^', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
```

Note that there are several other major changes in Oscar 2, so it's important to use the right version of documentation, otherwise you will run into other issues as well.

Comment: Could you help me here - related to oscar ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74911506/django-3-2typeerror-issubclass-arg-1-must-be-a-class